# Unable to negate a combination of words using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I am unable to negate a combination of words using [regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester).

#First Word - Test Company

I have used this regex `[^#First Word][^\s-][A-Za-z0-9\s]+`, but when I am using it with `Winautomatation` it returns only `st Company` and skips first 2 chars.

I want to remove `#First Word` from the string and get the remaining text from the string. Please help me find out a way to fix this.

I am using Regxstorm to build this regular expression.

Comment: A character class using `[^]` does not work like that. It matches any character that is not listed in the class. Do you mean like this? `^#First Word\s-\s(?=[A-Za-z0-9])` https://regex101.com/r/AcWoow/1

Answer (score 1):

Using `[^` means a negated character class and as it is not followed by a quantifier, it will match a single char which is not any of the listed.

Instead of using `?!`, you could use `(?=` to assert one of the chars `[A-Za-z0-9]`

You could match what you want to remove instead by matching the beginning followed by a hyphen between 2 whitespace chars.

```
^#First Word\s-\s(?=[A-Za-z0-9])
```

- `^` Start of string
- `#First Word` Match literally
- `\s-\s` Match a hyphen between 2 whitespace chars
- `(?=[A-Za-z0-9])` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is a char a-z or A-Z or 0-9

[.NET Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%23First+Word%5cs-%5cs%28%3f%3d%5bA-Za-z0-9%5d%29&i=%23First+Word+-+Test+Company&r=) *(Click on the Context tab)*

Another way around is to use a capturing group for what you want to keep, and match what you want to remove. In the replacement use the capturing group.

```
^#First Word\s-\s([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\s[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%23First+Word%5cs-%5cs%28%5bA-Za-z0-9%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5cs%5bA-Za-z0-9%5d%2b%29*%29&i=%23First+Word+-+Test+Company&r=%241)